# OpenStreetMap tiles by here's api

Tags: openstreetmap, here-api

I am writing mobile application with apache cordova engine.
I need tile and geocoder(reverse geocoder) server, for this reason I want to use here-api.

I need something as [OSM](http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=10/40.0886/44.6855), with buildings, street names... etc.
How I need  request to get this type of tiles?
Or, Is it possible to get [OSM](http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=2/15.6/100.2) tiles by here's servers?

Basically I need tiles of Armenian.

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get OSM tiles via HERE servers. I believe you are looking for this:

https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-map-tile/topics/quick-start.html

And then this:

https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/geocoder/topics/quick-start.html

You'll have to sign up for a plan before you can use it though:
https://developer.here.com/plans/api/consumer-mapping